# jQuery sortable shows wrong data values in Meteor template

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, meteor, meteor-blaze

#### video-cap.html

```
<div class="caption-sort">
    {{#each captions}}
    <div class="box caption module-sm">

        <div class="{{captionClasses}}">

            {{#if equals @index 0}}
            <p style="font-weight: bold;">First 3 Seconds</p>
            {{/if}}

            <textarea name="caption" class="caption-text">{{ this.caption }}</textarea>

            <select name="clip" class="clip-select" data-placeholder="Clip">
                <option value="">None</option>
                {{#each ../sources}}
                <option {{ selected ../clip @index }} value="{{ @index }}">
                    {{ clipName this.nickname @index }}
                </option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>

            <input name="start" class="timestamp" value="{{ this.start }}"/>
            <input name="end" class="timestamp" value="{{ this.end }}"/>

            <a data-index="{{@index}}"><i class="icon icon-close"></i></a>

        </div>

    </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

#### video-cap.js

```
var saveVideo = function(container){

    var captions = [];

    $('.caption').each(function(){

        var value = {
            'caption': $(this).find('.caption-text').val(),
            'clip': $(this).find('[name="clip"]').val(),
            'start': $(this).find('[name="start"]').val(),
            'end': $(this).find('[name="end"]').val(),
        };

        captions.push(value);

    });

    data.captions = captions;

    Meteor.call('updateArticle', the_id, data);
};
```

After applying jQuery UI's sortable to `.caption-sort` div, the data are showing wrong order sometimes on `.captions` after drag/dropping an item. I have also tried using `console.log(data)` inside the each() method, and it show the values are there in right order after a drop. But it's not showing on the template in correct order. Guess, it's a problem coming from reactivity. How can I solve this?

### Demo:

[image]

Comment: What do you mean? Can you give a scenario example. (e.g. the template loads and the captions are in order X, you drag and drop the bottom to the top, then when you run your save video function the captions are in the original order?).  Provide a scenario like that to explain your problem so its clear.